# for loop argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

Tags: python, api, for-loop, outlook, runtime-error

I have problems with my python for loop, because it runs into the following error after a few mails:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

So far I have not been able to find a solution to my problem.

Here is the code I mentioned:

```
for message in testing.get_messages():
    if '<noticket>' in message.subject:
        message.mark_as_read()
        print(message)
    else:
        print ("Checking...")
```

I use [O365](https://pypi.org/project/O365/) as a Python package.

Comment: Apparently, `testing.get_messages() is None`

Comment: Sounds like `testing.get_messages()` is not returning anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, `message.subject` is `None`. If I were you, I'd adjust the code this way:

```
if message.subject is not None and '<noticket>' in message.subject:
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply.

I had the `messages` displayed and found that one mail di not have a subject.

Comment: @darkphex Yeah, that's what I suspected :) You're welcome, however, if the answer helped you, I'd appretiate if you accepted it C:

Answer (score 0):

I bet it can help:

```
if testing.get_messages() is not None:
    for message in testing.get_messages():
    if '<noticket>' in message.subject:
        message.mark_as_read()
        print(message)
    else:
        print ("Checking...")
```